# Google Identity Toolkit and facebook

Tags: facebook, google-identity-toolkit

I am developing an application for android that will leverage google identity toolkit for authentication. Furthermore, the tokens obtained from the authentication will be used by an intermediate server to retrieve friend lists from the due social networks used to authenticate (e.g. Facebook). For this, I assume I need an OpenID of Web application retrieved from Google developer console, am I right? And then, the intermediate server would have a rest api for the android application to contact and perform logins?

On Facebook, am I supposed to configure two distinct applications? One for web and another for android.

The architecture would be something like:
[image]

Kind regards

Comment: If you want any information from the FB API, then you have to have your users login to your Facebook app.

Comment: can't i leverage google identity toolkit to retrieve facebook tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create one application at Facebook, but the application should contain two platforms (one is Android, the other is web). See https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart#optional_step_4_facebook_integration for the instruction.

In your Android app, you can add desired scopes when initializing the GitkitClient using  GitkitClientBuilder.addScopes(IdProvider.FACEBOOK, Arrays.asList("user_friends")). See https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/reference/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClientBuilder for the API reference.

After the user signs into your Android app, you can get the Facebook access token using Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken(), and sends the access token to your server. Your server can then call Facebook Graph API with that access token.

Comment: ok. I thought so because i could only find, either tutorials for pure android apps and others for web apps. I couldn't find a tutorial where the android application would use an intermediate server to perform a three legged oauth. I guess i have to authenticate directly with the facebook server and then send the token to the intermediate server